# Struggling with classes

Tags: set-theory, type-theory

I am still struggling with the concept of classes in ZF set theory. From Jech, Set Theory, p.5:

[image]

That means:

- For every formula $\varphi(x)$ there is a class (which is definable). There are countably many definable classes.
- For every formula $\varphi(x,y_1,\dots,y_n)$ and every tuple of sets $p_1,\dots,p_n$ there is a class (which is definable, when the sets $p_1,\dots,p_n$ are definable). There are "countably many times class-many", i.e. class-many such classes.

My questions are:

- Can the concept of "arbitrary collections" of sets be sensibly conceived that are not even classes, i.e. not given by a formula + parameters? 
  (Possible answer: No, because we cannot talk about them.)
- Can the classes of [NGB set theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory) be conceived as "arbitrary collections"?

If we consider sets (of ZF set theory) as the base type ("type 0"), there are three candidates for "type 1" as collections of sets:

1. sets of sets (collections that are co-extensive with sets)
2. classes of sets (collections that are given by a formula/property)
3. arbitrary collections of sets

Have all of these "type theories" been worked out, or do some of them simply not work?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is quite right to say that there are countably many definable classes. In the context of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, countability is only defined for objects in the domain of discourse (thought of as sets.) Definable classes correspond to formulas, which are objects in an informal meta-theory.  One could try to get around this distinction somehow, but there are two problems.

1. Although one can define a set $\text{Form}$ of elements of $V_\omega$ that code formulas, it's not generally possible to obtain a bijection between $\text{Form}$ and the collection of definable *sets*, nor is it even generally possible to formalize what it would mean to do so.  The naive attempt fails because of Tarski's theorem on the undefinability of truth.
2. Obtaining a bijection between $\text{Form}$ and the collection of definable *classes* is even more problematic, because the elements of the bijection  would be sets (simply because in the $\mathsf{ZFC}$ context only sets can appear on the left side of "$\in$") but some of the classes in the desired range are proper classes.

I think it is fair to say that classes in the sense of $\mathsf{NBG}$ could be considered as "arbitrary collections" of sets, in the sense that if $\kappa$ is an inaccessible cardinal then $V_\kappa$ together with the collection of all subsets of $V_\kappa$ (that is, with $V_{\kappa+1}$) forms a model of $\mathsf{NBG}$.  However, the "intended model" of $\mathsf{NBG}$ is sometimes considered to be $V_\kappa$ together with all subsets that are first-order definable over $V_\kappa$.  The intended model of [Morse–Kelley set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse-Kelley_set_theory) is $V_\kappa$ together with *all* subsets of $V_\kappa$, so perhaps it is a better candidate for your purposes.

I don't know the answer to your last question about type theories.

Comment: Every model of $\sf MK$ is a model of $\sf NBG$. So as an "intended model" goes, I'd think that $(V_\kappa,\operatorname{Def}(V_\kappa),\in)$ is a better fit.

Comment: @Asaf I think you are right.  I had just looked at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NBG_set_theory#Model_theory, which confused me.  i don't know why it says "$\Delta_0$" there.